# Why can I add, but not remove an element from a set

Tags: react-native

I’m trying to update the notification count in my database.

I’m doing this by creating a set, which I add a UID to when I want to add to the notification count and removes a UID from the set when I want to subtract from  the notification count.

I then take the size of the set and update the notification count.

the updateNotificationCount function is triggered by a lower order component.

However I can only get the database to update when isNewMatch is true. Why won’t it update the database when isNewMatch is false?

```
state = {notificationSet: new Set()}


updateNotificationCount = (uid, isNewMatch) => {

      if (isNewMatch) {
        this.setState(({ notificationSet }) => ({
          notificationSet: new Set(notificationSet).add(uid)
        }));
      }

      else {
        this.setState(({ notificationSet }) => {
          const newNotificationSet = new Set(notificationSet);
          newNotificationSet.delete(uid);

          return {
            notificationSet: newNotificationSet
          };
        });
      };

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do `new Set()` every time because you already initialize the state with `new Set()` so now you just do as follow:

```
state = {notificationSet: new Set()}


updateNotificationCount = (uid, isNewMatch) => {
  let notificationSet;
  if (isNewMatch) {
    notificationSet=this.state.notificationSet;
    notificationSet.add(uid);
    this.setState({
      notificationSet: notificationSet
    });
  } else {
    notificationSet=this.state.notificationSet;
    notificationSet.delete(uid);
    this.setState({
       notificationSet : notificationSet
    });
  };
```

}